# Is this sock-puppetry?

Tags: discussion, reputation, sock-puppets

Check out this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626693/im-a-good-c-desktop-programmer-will-it-be-easy-for-me-to-program-windows-mobil

This really seems like the two accounts are either the same person or colluding with each to game the system.  4 minutes between question and accepted answer...

Comment: They didn't even up-vote each other.

Comment: I've always thought the smartest thieves were the ones stealing just enough to not raise any flags...

Comment: "Oh look! No upvotes! They must be gaming the system!"

Comment: Technically, the question title has nothing to do with the thing you're asking about: Using sockpuppets to upvote your own questions and answers is not rep-whoring.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the usage of both accounts, I see no other similar activities.

Answer (score 6):

C# is one of the most heavily-subscribed tags, so 4 minutes is a perfectly reasonable window in which to receive an answer to a simple question.

(Orthogonal random thought: It would be interesting to see a list of the highest tags considered "interesting" and "ignored" by the user base. I expect this information is not in the data dump; would it be available via stackQL?)

Comment: 4 minutes on C# is *slow*....

Answer (score 3):

Is it only the time difference that bothers you?  Or do you have other evidence?  Seems to me that the OP simply got an answer that he liked and accepted it.

Comment: The time difference made me wonder; but the tone of the question and the answer really makes me wonder about collusion...

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonably common to get my answers to c#, .NET and ASP.NET questions accepted in well under 4 minutes, since those make up 3 of the top 4 topics and the top 4 tags' activity represents as much as the next 10 combined.